# multi-character character constant [-Werror,-Wmultichar]

Tags: c, char, load, cs50

(lines 43-56) I am attempting to implement load function for pset 5. I created a nested while loop, first one for iterating until the end of file and the other until end of each word. I created char *c to store whatever "string" I scan from dictionary, but when I compile

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    //create a trie data type
    typedef struct node
    {
        bool is_word;
        struct node *children[27]; //this is a pointer too!  
    }node;

    FILE *dptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if(dptr == NULL)
    {
       printf("Could not open dictionary\n");
       unload();
       return false;
    }

    //create a pointer to the root of the trie and never move this (use traversal *)
    node *root = malloc(sizeof(node));
    char *c = NULL;

    //scan the file char by char until end and store it in c
    while(fscanf(dptr,"%s",c) != EOF)
    {
       //in the beginning of every word, make a traversal pointer copy of root so we can always refer back to root
       node *trav = root;

       //repeat for every word
       while ((*c) != '/0')
       {
        //convert char into array index
       int alpha = ((*c) - 97);

       //if array element is pointing to NULL, i.e. it hasn't been open yet,
        if(trav -> children[alpha] == NULL)
            {
            //then create a new node and point it with the previous pointer. 
            node *next_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
            trav -> children[alpha] = next_node; 

            //quit if malloc returns null
            if(next_node == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Could not open dictionary");
                    unload();
                    return false;
                }

            }

        else if (trav -> children[alpha] != NULL)
            {
            //if an already existing path, just go to it
            trav = trav -> children[alpha];
            }   
       }
        //a word is loaded. 
        trav -> is_word = true;

    }
}
```

Error:

```
dictionary.c:52:23: error: multi-character character constant [-
       Werror,-Wmultichar]
       while ((*c) != '/0')
```

I think this means `'/0'` should be a single character, but I don't know how else I would check for end of the word! 
I also get another error message saying:

```
dictionary.c:84:1: error: control may reach end of non-void function [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
    }
```

I've been playing with it for a while now, and it is frustrating. Please help, and if you find any additional bugs, I'll be glad!

Comment: `'/0'` ----> `'\0'`

Comment: @rsp Or just 0, no quotes, no confusion.

Comment: Or `'??/0'` (in case you have no `\ `).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want '\0' (null terminating character) instead of '/0'.
Additionally, don't forget to return a bool at the end of your function !

Comment: Thanks! What a mistake